# Parsing with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I would like to parse an html code that looks like this:

```
<div>
<span>Current Status</span>FINAL DECISION </div>
<div>
<span>Applicant</span>GC Planning Partnership Ltd </div>
<div>
<span>Agent</span>GC Planning Partnership Ltd </div>
<div>
<span>Wards</span>Springfield Ward </div>
<div>
<span>Location Co ordinates</span>Easting 534379 Northing 187690 </div>
<div>
<span>Parishes</span> </div>
<div>
<span>OS Mapsheet</span>  </div>
<div>
```

Now, I don't want to get the text that is in-between the `<span>` tags, but rather the information right after it. From the example above, i would like to extract the values like "Final Decision", "Springfield Ward" or similar. I am very new to parsing html and i have no clue of how to get there.

I would be very happy for any hint or idea!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the text after a `span` element with a specific text - you can find the `span` element by text first and then get the [`.next_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
soup.find("span", text="Current Status").next_sibling
```

If, though you want to loop over all the `span` elements and for each `span` element get the next text sibling:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

for span in soup.find_all("span"):
    next_text = span.next_sibling
    if isinstance(next_text, NavigableString):
        print(next_text)
```